# Error running Mongod on Docker: invalid config file

Tags: mongodb, docker

I'm trying to run a MongoDB instance with docker but it can't read my configuration file. The error displayed is:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-03-03T20:12:52.875Z"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23320,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Option: Given key is deprecated. Please use preferred key instead.","attr":{"deprecatedKey":"net.ssl.PEMKeyFile","preferredKey":"net.tls.certificateKeyFile"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-03-03T20:12:52.875Z"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23320,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Option: Given key is deprecated. Please use preferred key instead.","attr":{"deprecatedKey":"net.ssl.CAFile","preferredKey":"net.tls.CAFile"}}
BadValue: --fork has to be used with --logpath or --syslog
```

Mongo config file (this is valid for standalone MongoDB):

```
# mongod.conf

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /etc/mongod/data
  journal:
    enabled: true

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: #true
  path: /etc/mongod/mongod.log

net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
  tls:
    mode: requireSSL
    certificateKeyFile: /etc/mongod/ca.pem
    CAFile: /etc/mongod/ca.crt
security.clusterAuthMode: x509
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mongo
RUN mkdir -p /etc/mongod/data
VOLUME /etc/mongod
COPY mongod.conf /etc/mongod
COPY ca.pem /etc/mongod
COPY ca.crt /etc/mongod
EXPOSE 27017
```

Commands for running the container:

```
sudo docker build -t mongo_1cd .
sudo docker run -v mongo_db:/etc/mongod -p 27017:27017 mongo_1cd --config /etc/mongod/mongod.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [docker VOLUME statement docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#notes-about-specifying-volumes):

> #### Notes about specifying volumes
>
> Keep the following things in mind about volumes in the Dockerfile.
>
> - ...
> - Changing the volume from within the Dockerfile: If any build steps change the data within the volume after it has been declared, those changes will be discarded.

Try moving the copy commands to above the VOLUME command?

Comment: Thank you, I was mistaken. I moved VOLUME down (below the last COPY)  but still, the problem continues. I really don't know what else is incorrect. The config file is correct for a standalone mongo.